# determining which id's have a time point that's earlier than another time point in R

Tags: r, datetime, time

I am trying to find a way to return subject_ids with time_2 that's earlier than time_1

| subject_id | Time_1 | Time_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 191-5467 | 18:00 | 20:00 |
| 191-6784 | 18:30 | 18:50 |
| 191-3457 | 19:00 | 21:45 |
| 191-0987 | 19:30 | 20:00 |
| 191-1245 | 19:45 | 19:00 |
| 191-2365 | 20:00 | 19:00 |

So in this case the code would return subject id's 191-1245 and 191-2365 because both their time_2 is earlier than time_1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(strptime(Time_2, '%H:%M') < strptime(Time_1, '%H:%M')) %>% 
  pull(subject_id)
[1] "191-1245" "191-2365"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to datetime with `POSIXct` and do the `subset`

```
subset(df1, as.POSIXct(Time_2, format = "%H:%M") < 
    as.POSIXct(Time_1, format = "%H:%M") )$subject_id
[1] "191-1245" "191-2365"
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, subject_id[as.ITime(Time_2) < as.ITime(Time_1)]]
[1] "191-1245" "191-2365"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", 
"191-0987", "191-1245", "191-2365"), Time_1 = c("18:00", "18:30", 
"19:00", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00"), Time_2 = c("20:00", "18:50", 
"21:45", "20:00", "19:00", "19:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the @Jilber Urbina answer, but using `lubridate`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df1 |>
  # Transform Time_1 and Time_2 to hour minutes with hm
  mutate(across(starts_with("Time"), hm)) |>
  # Filter to condition of interest
  filter(Time_2 < Time_1) |>
  # Pull the column with the id values
  pull(subject_id)
```

Comment: Isnt `dplyr` considered a tidyverse approach though?

Comment: Yes, I should had made the emphasis on the use of `lubridate`.